# Bug in the routine converting RGB to TSL and back

Tags: rgb, color-space

I am trying the TSL color space (Tint Saturation Luminance). Reading this wiki page

[TSL color space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TSL_color_space)

I have tried to code two simple rgb2tsl and tsl2rgb routines:

```
/// input: r,g,b in [0..1]
/// output: t,s,l in [0..1]
void    RGB2TSL( float  r, float    g, float    b, float    &t, float   &s, float &l )
{
    float   rn, gn;
    if ( r+g+b == 0.0f )
    {
        t = s = l = 0.0f;
        return  ;
    }
    rn = r/(r+g+b);
    gn = g/(r+g+b);
    float   r1, g1;
    r1 = rn-1.0f/3.0f;
    g1 = gn-1.0f/3.0f;
    l = 0.299*r+0.587*g+0.114*b;
    if ( g1 > 0 )
        t = (1.0f/(2.0f*PI))*atan2f(r1, g1) + 1.0f/4.0f;
    else if ( g1 < 0 )
        t = (1.0f/(2.0f*PI))*atan2f(r1, g1) + 3.0f/4.0f;
    else
        t = 0;
    s = sqrtf(9.0f/5.0f*(r1*r1+g1*g1));
}



/// input: t,s,l in [0..1]
/// output: r,g,b in [0..1]
void    TSL2RGB( float  t, float    s, float    l, float    &r, float   &g, float   &b )
{
    float   r1, g1, k, x;
    x = -sinf(2*PI*t);
    if ( x != 0 )
        x = cosf(2*PI*t)/x;
    if ( t > 0.5f )
        g1 = -s*sqrtf(5.0f/(9.0*(x*x+1.0f)));
    else if ( t < 0.5f )
        g1 = s*sqrtf(5.0f/(9.0*(x*x+1.0f)));
    else
        g1 = 0;

    if ( t == 0 )
        r1 = (sqrtf(5.0f)/3.0f)*s;
    else
        r1 = x*g1+1.0f/3.0f;

    k = 1.0f/(0.185*r1+0.473*g1+0.114);

    r = k*r1;
    g = k*g1;
    b = k*(1-r1-g1);
}
```

Please don't consider the code quality, just focus on the fact that there is an error I am unable to find: when I convert a rgb triple to tsl triple and, without changing anything, I convert it back to r, g, b, I don't get the original image, but really different and wrong in any possible way!

Answer (score 0):

RGB2TSL looks good to me, however there are clipping issues I believe. I think some values need to be clamped, but I'm not sure myself exactly which ones.